# Log into site and download file via PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

Not sure if this is even possible but since Verizon does not have an API set for this I thought I would look for an alternative.

As a verizon customer I can login to myverizon.com and from there they have a link to download an .XLS sheet with all of my recent history.

I would like to automate this process somehow but not sure if there is a way to create a session on another site with a valid username/password and then process to pull the file once credentials have been verified?

Right now I have to manually downlaod the XLS sheet and import into an application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the CURL Library for this in PHP.  It will allow you to post login credentials and save the cookie.

[Login CURL Example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ebay_login.html)

The above link demonstrates a login to Ebay using CURL

Comment: And you'll have to adapt the details of what to POST and where. To figure that out, you can view source of the login page in your browser and/or use some kind of traffic sniffing browser plugin...

Comment: @grossvogel Good point.  I like to use the net tab of the firefly addon for firefox for the sniffing.

Comment: So at a highlevel the process would be to
1. POST login info via CURL
2. Save cookie in response
3. Use CURL again to send the request to pull the file while also sending the cookie?

Comment: Exactly.. first save the cookie with the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR when you post.  On the next page use the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option to use the cookie file created.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there should be a way.

I cannot give you an instruction since I am not a Verizon customer. But you could start by trying to automate the XLS retrieval with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Then, if you want to do it via PHP/cURL (as is suggested by your tags), you could translate the Selenium file to corresponding cURL requests.

Update: Also, please make sure that this is okay according to the terms and conditions of your contract with Verizon.